# Sort dataframe by element of vector

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe implemented with Apache Spark which looks like this:

```
id      vector
1       [0.456,0.789]
2       [0.123,0.356]
...
```

I want to sort this dataframe by the second element of that vector. I allready have something like this:

```
val sortedDF = df.sort(desc("vector"))
```

Ofcourse this results in an exception saying:

```
cannot resolve 'probability DESC' due to data type mismatch: cannot sort data type vector;
```

I don't seem to find how to specify the second element of the vector in my sort function.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**UPDATE** This dataframe can take up to 3 million rows, so I don't know if it is effecient to create a new a dataframe with id and only the second element of the vector to sort.

Comment: How do you define the order in your vector ?

Comment: @eliasah the vector is actually the probability result of a classification model.

Comment: yes and how does that define the order on which you want to sort ?

Comment: the vector represents the probabilty for each class (0.0, 1.0). and I want to change the order of my df based on the probabilty of class 1.0 (the second element of the vector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it directly but it is possible to use an UDF to convert `vector` to `array` and extract individual elements you want to for sorting:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}

val to_array = udf((v: Vector) => v.toDense.values)

val df = Seq("[0.0,  1.0]", "[1.0, 0.0]").map(Vectors.parse(_))
  .zipWithIndex
  .toDF("vector", "idx")

df.orderBy(to_array($"vector"))
df.orderBy(to_array($"vector").getItem(1).desc)
```

If vector is large and you plan to access only a single element it can be more efficient to do it directly:

```
val apply_vec = udf((v: Vector, i: Int) => Try(v(i)).toOption)

df.orderBy(apply_vec($"vector", lit(1)))
```

Comment: yea, I just found something similar: 
val getProbOne = udf((p: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) => p(1))
val sortedPredictions = predictions.orderBy(getProbOne($"probability"))